# .Net 3.5 app on Win PE 4.0 image

Tags: winpe

Assuming a WinPE 4.0 image is setup correctly with the WinPE-NetFx4.cab, WinPE-NetFx4_en-us.cab and prerequisite packages like WMI, should an app built in Visual Studio 2008 for .NET 3.5 execute?  Or, is the app linked to strong name signed 3.5 assemblies such that it will not use the equivalent ones in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using WinPE 4.0 and experienced the same issue. Most of my app developed using earlier version of .NET Framework (.NET 3.0 & 3.5) will not execute (execute but nothing show up on screen)

A further investigation was made into the WinPE 4.0 WIM's Windows directory `"Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework"` show only signs of version 4 (for my case v4.0.30319) was installed (WinPE-NetFx4.cab).

This concludes Microsoft's WinPE 4.0 only supports .NET Framework 4.

In order to make your app work again, re-compiled them using .NET Framework 4 assemblies.